# Maven ignoring a ParameterizedTest

Tags: java, maven, junit

I´m trying to execute the test of a project using Maven, but Maven does not execute the test of a ParameterizedTest

Test file:

```
public class MapReaderTest {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"})
    void invalidMapTest(String mapLetter){
        String map = "./errorMap" + mapLetter + ".txt";
        String path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(map).getPath();
        assertThrows(MapInvalidLevelException.class, ()->new MapReader(path));
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Maven results:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running es.upm.pproject.sokoban.util.MapReaderTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
```

Comment: Do you have your plugin in pom configured for running JUnit5 tests?